# Balanced partition of $\{\ln 3, \ln 4,\dots,\ln n\}$

Tags: logarithms, set-partition

For a positive integer $n\ge 3$, let $A_n=\{\ln 3, \ln 4,\dots,\ln n\}$. Does there exist $N$ such that for all $n>N$, the set $A_n$ can be partitioned into two sets so that their sums differ by no more than $1$?

I think for odd $n$ it might be possible to partition the set as $\{\ln 3,\ln 5,\dots,\ln n\}$ and $\{\ln 4,\ln 6,\dots,\ln (n-1)\}$. The difference of sums is $\ln\left(\frac{3\cdot 5\cdot\dots n}{4\cdot 6\cdot\dots(n-1)}\right)$. The ratio within $\ln$ shouldn't be too large (we require it to be no more than $e$).

Comment: The product $\frac{3 \cdot 5 \cdot \ldots \cdot n}{4 \cdot 6 \cdot \ldots \cdot (n - 1)}$ seems to diverge. It starts with $\frac{3 \cdot 5}{4} > 3$ and, at each stage, is multiplied by $\frac{n}{n - 1} > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\ln\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{k(k+3)}=\ln\frac{k^2+3k+2}{k^2+3k}=\ln\left(1+\frac2{k^2+3k}\right)\lt\frac2{k^2+3k}\;.
$$

Thus

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\ln(j+4k)+\ln(j+4k+1)+\ln(j+4k+2)-\ln(j+4k+3)\right)
&\lt\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{(j+4k)^2+3(j+4k)}
\\
&\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{(1+4k)^2+3(1+4k)}
\\
&=
\frac\pi{12}+\frac{\ln2}2
\\
&\lesssim0.61\;.
\end{align}

So we only need one set for each non-zero residue modulo $4$ that has difference less than $0.39$, e.g.:

$$
\ln3+\ln4+\ln5-\ln6-\ln7=\ln\frac{10}7\lesssim0.36\;,\\
\ln4+\ln5+\ln7-\ln3-\ln6-\ln8=\ln\frac{35}{36}\gtrsim-0.03\;,\\
\ln3+\ln4+\ln5+\ln7-\ln6-\ln8-\ln9=\ln\frac{35}{36}\gtrsim-0.03\;.
$$